# What material is window insulation film?

Tags: windows, winterizing

That clear, heat shrink plastic film they use to insulate windows... Does anyone know exactly what type of plastic it is? Can't find anything searching.

I have a project I think it might be good for that requires gluing it and I'd like to know what it's made of to use the most appropriate adhesive. If anyone has done this, recommendations on adhesive will also be appreciated it.

Comment: Have you tried a [patent search](https://www.google.com/?tbm=pts&hl=en)? That might be the only way to discover the specific recipe for each manufacturer.

Comment: @Tester101 that's a good idea. I read a few patents but they're still a bit vague. One new component that did come up is polylactic acid. I think I'll just treat it as generic plastic and use a PVA glue. That shouldn't cause it to deteriorate.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Wikipedia search leads me to say its [Polyolefin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyolefin) (also see [Shrink Wrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrink_wrap)):

> The most commonly used shrink wrap is polyolefin. It is available in a variety of thicknesses, clarities, strengths and shrink ratios. The two primary films can be either crosslinked, or non crosslinked. Other shrink films include PVC and several other compositions.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrink_wrap

Any adhesive that will adhere to "plastics" should work fine.

Comment: I ran across polyolefin while searching but I couldn't find any definitive info.

Comment: From the wikipedia article you provided, Polyolefin appears to be a very broad category of plastics, which includes polyethylene, the stuff that milk jugs are made of.   I don't think your answer is specific enough.

Comment: @Edwin I don't think there is any specific answer other than the general chemicals used. I have to imagine that each manufacture will have their own "recipe" for this.

Comment: @Steven I think I see your point of view, but since the most common plastics, Polyethylene and Polypropylene are polyolefins, Your answer is the same as "It's made of plastic".  From my experience, these plastics alone do not have shrink wrap effect when heated. Although, for all I know, another polyolefin can be layered to produce the effect, but that still leaves the answer incomplete.

Comment: If that's the case then I would argue this is off topic for this site and a better fit for http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/